# Extracting different statistics from the same iteration of a for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I would like to create a data frame between two variables that are linked to the same distribution for each iteration.

```
sim_df <- rep(NA, 1000)
for (i in 1:1000) { 

#randomly generated distribution
dist = sample(c(0:200), 10, replace = TRUE)
dist = as.data.frame(dist)

#calculated statistics
dist_mean = mean(a[,1])
dist_sd   = sd(a[,1])

#build data frame
df = data.frame(dist_mean, dist_sd)

#return
sim_df = df[i]
}
```

I am unsure how to define each column so that they can be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function which returns mean and sd for one iteration.

```
return_mean_sd <- function() {
  dist = sample(c(0:200), 10, replace = TRUE)
  c(mean = mean(dist), sd = sd(dist))
}
```

You can call this function `n` times to create a dataframe.

```
set.seed(123)
sim_df <- as.data.frame(t(replicate(100, return_mean_sd())))
head(sim_df)

#   mean   sd
#1 105.0 70.3
#2 119.7 44.3
#3  91.6 56.1
#4  91.5 58.7
#5  99.1 55.2
#6  90.0 52.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```r
set.seed(2021) # for reproducibility, do not use in production
sim_df <- replicate(1000, {
  dist = sample(c(0:200), 10, replace = TRUE)
  data.frame(dist_mean = mean(dist), dist_sd = sd(dist))
}, simplify = FALSE)

sim_df[1:3]
# [[1]]
#   dist_mean  dist_sd
# 1     143.1 40.04012
# [[2]]
#   dist_mean  dist_sd
# 1       119 55.65169
# [[3]]
#   dist_mean  dist_sd
# 1       103 44.23674
```

From here, if you want all of those in one frame, then

```r
sim_df1 <- do.call(rbind, sim_df)
nrow(sim_df1)
# [1] 1000
head(sim_df1)
#   dist_mean  dist_sd
# 1     143.1 40.04012
# 2     119.0 55.65169
# 3     103.0 44.23674
# 4     103.2 57.00838
# 5     124.3 50.74785
# 6     112.9 56.98041
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to generate a complete stream of realizations, convert them to a matrix and then generate the stats from the rows:

```
dist <- sample(c(0:200), 10 * 1000, replace = TRUE)
dist <- matrix(dist, ncol = 10)
means <- rowMeans(dist)
sds <- apply(dist, 1, sd)
df <- data.frame(means, sds)
head(df)
  means      sds
1  60.7 52.45750
2 124.3 65.82646
3 101.3 73.34856
4 116.4 39.37907
5  97.2 65.79227
6  94.7 58.27530
```